# Not able to start NFS In fedora25, getting error as Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked

Tags: linux, nfs, fedora-25

I'm trying to start NFS in Fedora25

```
[root@localhost tftpboot]# systemctl start nfs-server.service
```

Failed to start nfs-server.service: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked.

Which gave error as above and also status also shown inactive

```
[root@localhost tftpboot]# systemctl status nfs-server.service
 nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-03-30 19:02:10 IST; 2min 45s ago
  Process: 4886 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4883 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4880 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 981 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your own question to extend this info, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Tried below command for unmask "sudo systemctl unmask proc-fs-nfsd.mount" then " sudo service nfs restart". it worked